# Jquery functions not being triggered

Tags: html

I have a set of jquery functions that work very well until i update the system or do some modifications on the page. There i find out that they are not being triggered anymore. As if JQuery does not see them anymore so it can handle their events.

For example, let's say i have the 2 below functions and for some reason the Reject method is not being triggered anymore

```
$('body').on('click', '#approve', Approve);

$('body').on('click', '#reject', Reject);
```

All i do in my case to make it work is i move the Reject method to the top (before the Approve method) so JQuery kind of "sees it" and handle it. So the code becomes like this.

```
$('body').on('click', '#reject', Reject);

$('body').on('click', '#approve', Approve);
```

And of course after a while when the code change i am having the same problem with the approve method.
Does this make any sense? does anyone know why JQuery stop handling those events suddenly. Can this be related to some code in some other page that has been cached in the browser?

Comment: The given syntax is absolutely correct jQuery for 1.7 and above. Please provide more information.

Comment: show the function code ..

Comment: What 'changes' are you making?

Comment: could show the version of jquery and how you are importing.

Comment: @DavidThomas the changes are light modification in the html page or sometimes i add other pages with some other functionalities.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS the jquery version is 1.10.2

Comment: Why are you using such an antiquated version of jQuery?

Comment: did you clear cache and tried

Comment: @PavanKumarTS yes even clearing the cache won't work

Comment: @DavidThomas it's a system that i have to maintain